# Shopify admin API filter by updated_at not working

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I'm trying to filter by `updated_at` on shopify admin API of products. And it's not working, as it only returns me every product that's my request, could you please help me?

`https://nameoftheshop/admin/api/2024-01/products.json?limit=250&since_id=0&updated_at=2024-02-18T00:00:00.000Z`

Comment: You are asking for products with a since_id = 0? That is not gonna help you much. And if you also say show me products updated at 2024-02-18T00:00:00.000Z you might be very very lucky you got on at that exact moment. 

Shopify has search criteria clearly described like created_at_min or created_at_max, so you should style your efforts like that.